# How can you check if an excel cell is locked using Apache POI API?

Tags: apache-poi

How can you check if an excel cell is locked using Apache POI API? Have quickly checked the Javadoc for the Apache POI Cell interface but could not find a standard method for that. Is there any other method or a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is check if the CellStyle is locked.

```
boolean isLocked = cell.getCellStyle().getLocked();
```

See the documentation under CellStyle here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getLocked--